# `window.location.href` is just refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onsubmit, location-href

This is kind of confusing, but I'll try to explain it as well as I can. I have 4 `select` menus laid directly on top of each other with `absolute` positioning. At any one time, three of them are invisible (with `display: none;`) while 1 of them is visible (with `display: inline;`). I have a JavaScript code that detects which one is visible, and then it's supposed to get the value of an `input` field, append it on the value of the visible `select`, and go to that URL.

Here is the basic idea in code:

```
<form onsubmit="goTo()">

    <input type="text" id="query" value="" />

    <select class="service">
      <option value="https://www.google.com/search?q=" selected>Web</option>
      <option value="https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=">Images</option>
      <option value="https://www.google.com/maps?q=">Maps</option>
    </select>

    <select class="service">
      <option value="http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" selected>Web</option>
      <option value="http://search.yahoo.com/search/images?p=">Images</option>
      <option value="http://search.yahoo.com/search/video?p=">Videos</option>
    </select>

    <select class="service">
      <option value="http://www.bing.com/?q=" selected>Web</option>
      <option value="http://www.bing.com/images/?q=">Images</option>
      <option value="http://www.bing.com/videos/?q=">Videos</option>
    </select>

    <select class="service">
      <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/info.dogpl.t6.2/search/web?q=" selected>Web</option>
      <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/info.dogpl.t6.2/search/images?q=Greeny">Images</option>
      <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/info.dogpl.t6.2/search/video?q=">Videos</option>
    <select>

    <button type="submit">Search</button>
```

And the JavaScript (there is way more code than this, but I'll only include the relevant part:

```
function goTo() {
  var value
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('service');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if(elements[i].style.display === 'inline') {
        value = elements[i].value;
        window.location.href = value + document.getElementById("query").value;
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

My problem is that all that happens when I click submit is the page reloads.

http://jsfiddle.net/9BLAv/3/

Comment: can't use event handlers on `option` tag in IE, they won't register

Comment: This is only for Firefox (addon). I actually meant to take those out because they really aren't relevant to the problem

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle; it wouldn't let me paste anything into it.

Comment: You should provide us with the elements which have the `service` class.

Comment: you have no code showing to change value of `id="query"` which you need to create new url

Comment: Which element is having class as "service"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to stop the default action of the "submit" event, which is to reload the page.

Change the form tag to:

```
<form onsubmit='goTo(); return false'>
```

You could alternatively do this by explicitly preventing the default action by manipulating the event object, but I think returning `false` from the handler is pretty universal.